# Can a bridge be repeated?

Tags: musical-forms, repeats

A bridge is basically a section of the song that joins verses and choruses together, am I right? But can a bridge be repeated if the verse/chorus also repeats? I've tried Googling it, but I got some confusing results - some websites said it can, others said it can't.

Comment: Yes, you have my permission. And that of tens of thousands of other musos who do it all the time!! The so-called 'middle eight' of a lot of songs isn't eight bars long, nor in the middle, neither. Where did you get the idea we have to follow rules? Have you listened to enough songs that actually do have more than one bridge? Granted, it's not that many, but...  And if you found a song which did, and it broke the 'rules', what would you do?

Comment: A section connecting verse and chorus is typically called "pre-chorus". Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user1079505 - I'd never heard of a pre-chorus until I joined this stack. It was a 'bridge' for 40 years before that, to me. [Might be a transpondian difference]

Comment: You can DO ANYTHING in music. Really who is going to stop you the music police? The more pertinent question is, is it going to sound good if you do it? In music, there are no rules it is only about what sounds good

Comment: @Tetsujin if you'd write song structure of Metallica "Enter Sandman", would you call both "Sleep with..." and "Hush little baby" bridges? Or another name? Also, people also call B section in AABA form (which is not new at all), and that's definitely not the type of section that connects verse and chorus.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm sure to have seen some patrol at some point, upon crossing...

Comment: @Tetsujin to me a pre-chorus may come before most or all choruses, whereas a bridge can come anywhere, and usually only occurs once or twice per song. To answer the question, if you have only one, it's probably a bridge. but you can still call it a bridge if you have more than one.

Comment: It seems we have yet to find adequate distinction between what one would call a bridge & another a pre-chorus. On the right side of the pond, the bridge is what comes before the chorus. We just don't use 'pre-chorus' as a term. I haven't yet figured out what other people's definition may be in UK English - I'd always think a 'bit that happens only once' is a middle 8 [which has already been mentioned doesn't have to be in the middle & doesn't have to be 8 bars]. Back when I did a lot of writing, if a bit didn't fit any existing definition, we'd just call it "other bit" or "bit in D"...

Comment: @Tetsujin I think I'm familiar with wikipedia definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_structure#Bridge _A bridge may be a transition, but in popular music, it more often is "...a section that contrasts with the verse..."_

Comment: @user1079505 You have to be wary of Wikipedia sometimes, it often has a US bias & fails to recognise transpondian differences, especially on topics regarding the 'arts' rather than sciences or linguistics specifically. That entire article also is chock-full of citation warnings.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know this definition from other sources too. Perhaps indeed US sources, I never considered that. Anyway, I didn't intend to police the one and only correct usage of words. We all need to be mindful that various words are used in a various ways by various communities.

Comment: @user1079505 … which is precisely what I said 8 comments ago… and again 4 comments ago. Anyway, if you have an answer, please provide it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is entirely opinion-based, however…

People will tell you, you can't eat sprouts & custard, or put pineapple on pizza.

Sure you can, if that's what you like.
There's literally no rule, law, or edict to stop you - only people with different opinions.

<sup>*Of course, there **ought** to be such a law about pineapple on pizza ;))*</sup>

*Still opinion-based, but after comments…*
I'd say the primary purpose would be to add tension. Whenever I've used them it's been precisely for that… hold the audience expecting a chorus for longer, so the switch to chorus is 'bigger' for the final run to the finish. Alternatively, for an end repeating chorus, put a bridge before the first two, then let them run round after that. I've even ended on a bridge, to leave everything hanging…

Comment: Multiple bridges are a lot less contentious than sprouts & custard! (Actually, they aren't contentious at all.)

Comment: The only people who tell you, you cannot eat pineapple on pizza are the Italians

Comment: I like sprouts and I like custard. But...

Comment: BTW, the sprouts & custard thing did actually happen, though by accident. Waaaay back in school, one guy held out the wrong plate for custard & got it on his sprouts instead. They offered to re-plate the entire meal, but he said he'd eat it, just to see. He declared it "OK, but not something I ever need to try again" ;)

Comment: I seem to be getting downvotes from people who like pineapple on pizza. I can't imagine it could be a late surge from the sprouts & custard lobby ;))

Comment: -1 from me (even though I don't particularly disagree with the conclusion in this specific question). But please stop posting generic “anything in music is allowed” statements as answers. Yes, these are always technically correct, but **a)** they are generally misleading without the qualifier that everything “possible” will have an effect on the listener, which may or may not align with the composer's intentions. ...

Comment: **b)** in some cases it's not a matter of allowed or not, but _definition_. If the question is whether it's allowed to play a waltz in 4/4 then the answer is... kinda _no it's not allowed_ – not because anything stops you from [taking a waltz and changing it to be in 4/4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flohwalzer), but because that removes exactly the element that causes it to be a waltz in the first place. It's still music, but not a waltz. Similarly, there _could_ be an argument that it is the defining character of a bridge to only occur once in a piece, though I don't think that is the case.

Comment: (BTW, I actually like pizza with pineapple sometimes...)

Answer (score 6):

The websites aren't laying down rules.  (Or they shouldn't be.)   They're describing what they feel usually happens in some particular style of music.

Listen to some songs.  Listen to LOTS of songs!  Is there a bridge?   Is it repeated?

I think you'll find some songs where it is repeated, some where it isn't.  Can you see why each decision was made?   Perhaps the song builds up to the first chorus  and putting another bridge in would kill the momentum.   Perhaps where a second bridge could come there's a guitar solo instead (but is it acting as a sort of bridge into the last chorus?).   Or perhaps it's Verse-Bridge-Chorus all repeated.

Not fair, is it!  You come asking for rules and we insist on research instead!

Comment: @user87626 another way of looking at it: sometimes the rules describe the defining characteristics of a certain form.  If you don't comply with the rules, the song doesn't have the given form.  But generally it doesn't matter whether a song has a particular form unless you're writing it for a pedagogical assignment that requires the particular form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple answer is to this question, it is generally no, in my opinion.

There might be a bridge between two choruses at the end of a song, before an instrumental solo, before a key change, or before a build-up of tension and its release in electronic music.

Based on these uses, you could say that the bridge functions as a **transition between two contrasting sections** of a song or as **a contrasting section on its own**, the latter case being more common with pop music. Repetition of this part might make it a more structural part of the song, in which case you might call it something else, such as a "pre-chorus".

Of course, the real answer is, you can do whatever you want.